# Remove format characters from string

Tags: c#, string, pdf, format

I know i can do this one by one but i was curious if there is a way to remove all format characters from a single like this. Im using c# and pdfPig to build a pdf document.

```
 &lt;p&gt;Examples of vulnerability triggers:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbof pensionable age.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Disabilitor visual impairment(s).&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsterm ill-health.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Peowho are not of a mental capacity to make their own decisions.&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&avulnerability (e.g. redundancy)&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Young children&lt;/p&gt;
```

[image]

Comment: LIke this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/h2GKZM - or do you also want to remove the `<p>`?

Comment: In questions like this, please provide your expected output as well as what **you** have tried so far.

Comment: i need to remove everything from that string except the core text, give me one moment to manually remove all the junk so you can see an expected outcome. This is just a sample string.

Comment: Here a version which removes `<p>` aswell: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hw5j6N - I am using HtmlAgilityPack for it: https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/

Answer (score 0):

You could try with regex, try to run this:

```js
input =
    "&lt;p&gt;Examples of vulnerability triggers:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbof pensionable age.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Disabilitor visual impairment(s).&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsterm ill-health.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Peowho are not of a mental capacity to make their own decisions.&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&avulnerability (e.g. redundancy)&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;·&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Young children&lt;/p&gt;";

// replace all &nbsp; with space
input = input.replace(/nbsp;/g, "");
// replace all &lt; with <
input = input.replace(/&lt;\/?p/g, "");
// replace all &gt; with >
input = input.replace(/&gt;/g, "");
// replace all &amp; with &
input = input.replace(/&amp;/g, "");
console.log(input);
```

This is in Javascript but you can use the same regex in any language.